# Вопрос по ajax корзине

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте, есть функция

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".button_cart").click(function() {

            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            var id = $("input").eq(0).val();
            var name = $("input").eq(1).val();
            var price = $("input").eq(2).val();
            var qty = $("input").eq(3).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/shop/add_to_cart",
                data: {product_id: id, product_name: name, product_price: price,qty:qty},
                success: function(data){alert('Товар добавлен'+data)}
            });

            return false;

        });

    });
</script>
```

и Форма   обычная с полями, чет вставить сюда не получается не форматируется.
Суть в том что,в скрипте я беру значения с формы и отправляю в корзину, но скрипт берет с первой попавшийся формы, а как значение родительского элемента parent к ним добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = $(".parent > input").val(); // .parent пример
```

Comment: Теперь var id = $(".parent > input").eq(0).val();  
выводит undefined  
а var id = $("form > input").eq(0).val();  выводит правильно id только с первой формы  
  
  
как мне Вот сюда  
var id = $("input").eq(0).val();  
Как применить переменную parent которую я создал, сори может и глупые вопросы, ajax только начал учить

Comment: Класс .parent  был примером

   var id = parent.children()[0].value; и тд 4 и обхекта